# Hausdorff dimension of a Sierpinski-like triangle

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Define the set $A \subset \mathbb R^2$ by proceeding as follows. Let $A_0$ be a closed equilateral triangular region of side 1. $A_1$ are the three equilateral triangular regions of side $\frac 1 3$ in the corners of $A_0$. In general $A_{j+1}$ are the equilateral triangular regions in the corners of each triangle of $A_j$ and the side of each triangular region in $A_{j+1}$ is a third of the side of each triangular region of $A_j$. Now we define $$A := \bigcap_{j=0}^\infty A_j \; .$$
This construction process is shown here (the thin lines are not part of $A_j$):
[image: Construction of A]

Now I want to show, that $$\mathcal H^1(A) = 1 \; ,$$ where $\mathcal H^1(A)$ is the Hausdorff measure of $A$ with $s = 1$. I think that I've managed to show that $\mathcal H^1(A) \leq 1$, but I have problems to show that $\mathcal H^1(A) \geq 1$. My idea was to consider consider the projection $p: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, defined by $(x,y) \mapsto x$. By construction we have $p(A_j) = [0,1]$ for each $j \in \mathbb N$. Furthermore $p$ is Lipschitz with $\text{Lip}(p) = 1$. If I can show that $p(A) = [0,1]$, I'm finished, because then we have $$1 = \lambda^1(p(A)) = \mathcal H^1(p(A)) \leq \text{Lip}(p) \mathcal H^1(A) = \mathcal H^1(A) \; .$$
So my question is, if this idea is correct and does it hold that $p(A) = [0,1]$? If so, why does it hold?

Comment: This "triangle" is compact and the projection is continuous. Thus it suffices to show that the image is dense in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A_n$ is a nested sequence ($A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$) of compact sets  and $y \in p(A_n)$ for all $n$, where $p$ is a continuous map from $A_1$ to a Hausdorff space, then I claim $y \in p(\bigcap_n A_n)$.  Namely, let $x_n \in A_n$ with $p(x_n) = y$.
The sequence $x_n$ must have a limit point $x$, and it's easy to prove that $x$ is in all $A_n$ and $p(x) = y$..

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. This helped a lot. One little detail: I think we need to pass to a subsequence $\{ x_{n_k} \}_{k=0}^\infty$ of $\{ x_n \}_{n=0}^\infty$ to have the convergence of the sequence guaranteed. But it still works this way.

Comment: I wrote "limit point", not "limit".